# GORM for Rest (Grails)?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am doing some research on Grails and writing about what the future holds for it..

Something interesting jumped out in the RoadMap (http://grails.org/Roadmap)

**GORM for REST**

Anyone with more experience with Grails than me know what this would entail?

I am guessing some sort of CRUD operations through Web Services instead of using Hibernate to connect to an SQL database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is a [JSON RESTful API for GORM](http://www.grails.org/plugin/json-rest-api) which gives some insight on what `GORM for REST` is like:

- **GET** on /context/api/domain-class-name returns a list of domain objects (possible arguments are the same as for the DomainClass.list() method argument map)
- **POST** on /context/api/domain-class-name creates a new instance
- **GET** on /context/api/domain-class-name/id retrieves the given instance
- **PUT** on /context/api/domain-class-name/id updates the given instance by ID
- **DELETE** on /context/api/domain-class-name/id deletes the given instance

As far as to RESTy GORM that is scheduled for Grails 2.0, here is the [GORM Virtual REST domain objects](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GORM-Virtual-REST-domain-objects-td3087984.html) discussion on Grails mailing list:

*I am currently evaluating the use of grails to connect to other backend systems. Would it be possible to let the domain layer talk to CRUD REST services instead of a Database? It would be a bit like a XML backend.... We have got a very big backend where it is difficult to implement business logic, but we can manage to provide restful services. My idea is to have grails as a business / web application layer on top to deploy various systems to cross platform*

```
This feature is scheduled for development for Grails 2.0 
-- Graeme Rocher
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the intent is to apply the scaffolding pattern to a RESTful API out of the box.  There has been a JIRA entry around for several years for this.

Resulting JIRA:  http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2823

I also wouldn't be surprised if they took the dynamic finder idea and applied it to URL patterns.

`GET /book/findByTitle/Dune`

or

`GET /book/findByTitle?title=Dune&format=json`

or something like that.

I don't know exactly what is on the roadmap, but I imagine that the final product will have scaffold functionality (list,view,create,update,delete) through a RESTful interface plus some URL patterns that correspond to what you can currently do with the dynamic finders that GORM provides.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JAX-RS plugin. I suspect that will be the kind of thing they use.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I want to rain on the parade but why would I use REST for accessing database rather than directly through hibernate. It's bound to slow down the DB access.

Comment: Because you may not own the database, only a restful interface into it.  Consider the power of this when building a "mash-up" application